# Associative array ( hash table, tree, etc ) benchmark tool?

Tags: c, tree, hashmap, benchmarking, associative-array

Are there any tools for benchmarking associative arrays?

- Should be able to benchmark different types of keys, sparse/dense, long/short, few/many .
- Should perform operations insert, delete, query . As well as batch versions of these.

This means that hash tables can be benchmarked against tree structures and other retrieval structures.

Preferably written in C.

If there isn't anything quite like this:

- Any programs that generate these keys
- Any programs that help create an appropriate benchmarking environment ( fixed cores, fixed frequency, reserved process )

Comment: A rule for SO is that we don't recommend specific books, software, etc. so your question isn't on topic for SO